# FOSRestBundle parse headers

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am using FOSRestBundle in order to implement an API. I would like to parse HTTP headers that are sent to me from the client.

How can I access them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get headers from Request object in your controller methods.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function someAction(Request $request){
   $request->headers //get headers
}
```